# Check the Existence of a Network Interface Card Redhat

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, ruby

I'm aware that I can use `ethtool eth0|eth1|eth2` to check the existence of a NIC. 
But I wonder where the files are on the machine that contain information of an existing interface, as I need to use the Ruby language to check for available NICs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is /proc/net/dev, but I am sure there is an actual Ruby API to do this correctly.

see http://curioushq.blogspot.com/2011/04/listing-all-network-interfacesdevices.html

Answer (score 1):

Call `ethtool` as an external process and parse its output. If you want information related to IP settings, call `ifconfig` in preference to `ethtool`, because `ifconfig` is always present whereas `ethtool` will be present only if the system administrator has installed it. An alternative to `ifconfig` is `ip`, but it's not always present and its output is only marginally easier to parse than `ifconfig`'s, so use `ifconfig` if it provides the right output for you.